# Java long conversion into bytes

Tags: java, android

I am are trying to convert a long into a byte array to send out via BLE message. I have tried several different methods, but not been successful in converting the data from long into bytes. I have the long which I read time stable and then I want to convert into a byte, but keeping the numbers as example below:

// For example long -> 1620903871
long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;

```
               byte[] outgoingbytes = new byte[10];
               // this is the outcome of the data conversion and this how the data needs to presented in the bytes
               outgoingbytes[0] = 1;
               outgoingbytes[1] = 6;
               outgoingbytes[2] = 2;
               outgoingbytes[3] = 0;
               outgoingbytes[4] = 9;
               outgoingbytes[5] = 0;
               outgoingbytes[6] = 3;
               outgoingbytes[7] = 8;
               outgoingbytes[8] = 7;
               outgoingbytes[1] = 1;
```

Currently when I convert it into ASCII, but cannot get just the raw number. Any ideas how to the long into bytes?

Comment: A long consists of eight bytes. So you should send eight bytes. Each byte you can obtain by shifting and and-ing the right bits. You get an idea at the answer that is already given. If you want to keep the string "1620903871" then just send that string. And if you use a DataOutputStream you can use writeLong(). Unclear why you want it the way you described. All should go as the receiver expects.

Comment: `I am are trying to convert a long into a byte array`  So no. You are not. You are trying to convert a string in a byte array. But why? You can do that with String.getBytes() if needed.

Comment: I have a long i.e. 1620903871 and need to send it via BLE in a byte array. But when I convert it to string, bytes I get either ASCII i.e. 1 will become 31 (ASCII) I just want to send the value ie. 1 for the byte array would be [0] - 1 [2] - 6 [3] - 3 etc

Comment: String.getBytes("1620903871") will give them. But rather tell why you want to send the string representation of a long value. int value = Integer.valueOf("3") can be used then if i understand correct. A simple loop will give them. Or just subtract the ascii value of '0';

Comment: Many thanks, I know it's sounds madness but this is how the data needs to be sent. One question, I know I am going mad but why does long v = 0312; become 0b11001010 in bin (which becomes 202) surely in binary it would 0000-0011-000-0001-000-0010

Comment: Post your reproducable code as who knows what you are doing.

Comment: All the code is v = 0312; with the debug and watching the variable it states the binary 0b11001010. There is nothing else manipulating the variable. Just cannot understand were the binary comes from.

Comment: Literal number with 0-prefix is to be regarded as an octal number. Therefore "0312" = 000-011-001-010 = (3 * 8 + 1) * 8 + 2 = 202. Refer the [Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-OctalNumeral).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Java's DataInput and DataOutput interface and the implementations:

**DataInputStream:**

```
public final long readLong() throws IOException {
    readFully(readBuffer, 0, 8);
    return (((long)readBuffer[0] << 56) +
            ((long)(readBuffer[1] & 255) << 48) +
            ((long)(readBuffer[2] & 255) << 40) +
            ((long)(readBuffer[3] & 255) << 32) +
            ((long)(readBuffer[4] & 255) << 24) +
            ((readBuffer[5] & 255) << 16) +
            ((readBuffer[6] & 255) <<  8) +
            ((readBuffer[7] & 255) <<  0));
}
```

**DataOutputStream:**

```
/**
 * Writes a <code>long</code> to the underlying output stream as eight
 * bytes, high byte first. In no exception is thrown, the counter
 * <code>written</code> is incremented by <code>8</code>.
 *
 * @param      v   a <code>long</code> to be written.
 * @exception  IOException  if an I/O error occurs.
 * @see        java.io.FilterOutputStream#out
 */
public final void writeLong(long v) throws IOException {
    writeBuffer[0] = (byte)(v >>> 56);
    writeBuffer[1] = (byte)(v >>> 48);
    writeBuffer[2] = (byte)(v >>> 40);
    writeBuffer[3] = (byte)(v >>> 32);
    writeBuffer[4] = (byte)(v >>> 24);
    writeBuffer[5] = (byte)(v >>> 16);
    writeBuffer[6] = (byte)(v >>>  8);
    writeBuffer[7] = (byte)(v >>>  0);
    out.write(writeBuffer, 0, 8);
    incCount(8);
}
```